# 'if not or' not working in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this code in Ruby:

```
if @pass.nil?
        badpass(@nick)
elsif not clt.correctpassword?(@nick, @pass)
        badpass(@nick)
```

I wanted to condense it to a single line so I tried writing it as:

```
if not clt.correctpassword?(@nick, @pass) or @pass.nil?
        badpass(@nick)
```

But then `badpass(@nick)` doesn't get triggered for either cases, whereas it works in both cases in the top example.

Why does this happen?

Comment: It should work nothing wrong with code, check your `clt.correctpassword?(@nick, @pass)` what it returns and `@pass`.nil? value.

Comment: @PramodShinde `correctpassword?` uses `!results.empty?` at the end.

Comment: `badpass(@nick)` this will get executed only  if `clt.correctpassword?(@nick, @pass)` returns false and `@pass.nil` true or false, and why to use `!results.empty?` instead use `results.present?` it more simpler

Comment: Why does the first block work but the second block doesn't?

Comment: @PramodShinde - Look at the *order* of the expressions. (See my answer below.)

Answer (score 4):

In your revised code the tests are in the opposite order from the original. It's as if you had written:

```
if not clt.correctpassword?( @nick, @pass )
    badpass( @nick )
elsif @pass.nil?
    badpass( @nick )
end
```

Put the tests in the same order as the original and it will work like the original:

```
if @pass.nil? or not clt.correctpassword?( @nick, @pass )
    badpass( @nick )
end
```

Remember that Ruby, like many other languages, uses [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) for the logical operators `and`, `or`, `&&` and `||`. This means that it evaluates the expression to the left of the operator first, and then only evaluates the expression to the right of the operator if it needs to.

BTW, many Rubyists would write it this way instead:

```
badpass( @nick ) if @pass.nil? or not clt.correctpassword?( @nick, @pass )
```

That does the same thing; it's just a matter of which style you prefer.

If the `.correctpassword?` method is code that you can modify, then another nice option would be to add a nil test at the beginning of that method. In fact, you may as well test for nil on *both* `nick` and `pass`:

```
def correctpassword?( nick, pass )
    return false if nick.nil? or pass.nil?
    ... the rest of your code here ...
end
```

Then when you call this method you can simply use:

```
if not clt.correctpassword?( @nick, @pass )
    badpass( @nick )
end
```

or this simple code:

```
badpass( @nick ) unless clt.correctpassword?( @nick, @pass )
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not use `and`, `or` or `not` in conditions. They are for control flow and they offen lead to [precedence](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence#Operator_Precedence_Table) problems in conditions.

Let's transform your code:

```
if @pass.nil?
  badpass(@nick)
elsif not clt.correctpassword?(@nick, @pass)
  badpass(@nick)
end
```

Make it more Ruby-like:

```
if !@pass
  badpass(@nick)
elsif !clt.correctpassword?(@nick, @pass)
  badpass(@nick)
end
```

Combine conditions:

```
if !@pass || !clt.correctpassword?(@nick, @pass)
  badpass(@nick)
end
```

Simplefy condition ([De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws))

```
if !(@pass && clt.correctpassword?(@nick, @pass))
  badpass(@nick)
end
```

Or even more Ruby-like:

```
badpass(@nick) unless @pass && clt.correctpassword?(@nick, @pass)
```

And I agree with @MichaelGeary that you should move the check for the existence of `@pass` into the `correctpassword?` method...

Comment: What is the reasoning behind changing `.nil?` to `!`? I thought `.nil` was very "Ruby-like".